# Vuex Persistance in Nuxt using cookie-universal-nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

Need help to implement cookie-universal-nuxt with vuex-persistedstate. As mentioned in docs. VuexPersistedstate can use a custom storage element if getItem/setItem/removeItem are provided.

```
// ~/plugins/persistedState.js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
export default ({ app, store }) => {
  createPersistedState({
    storage: {
      getItem: (key) => app.$cookies.get(key),
      setItem: (key, value) =>
        app.$cookies.set(key, value, {
          path: '/',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        }),
      removeItem: (key) => app.$cookies.remove(key),
    },
  })(store)
}
```

With this code the page is not even loading throwing ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Answer (score 0):

vuex-persistedstate must be included as a NuxtJS plugin